# why use xsd with wsdl in java Web services

Tags: java, web, service, xsd, wsdl

In one of my project it is told write wsdl and xsd file to create web services in java 
It is necessary to always write xsd for wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

xsd is important for the data structure of the messages that will be sent between the client and the service hosting the web service. They ensure that the client cannot just out any arbitrary data fields from no where. So you will be sure when using xsds that the structure of the data will always be in the way that it is specified on the xsd. It's the same concept as the compiler of your code, that ensures that the syntax of your code follows a specified structure before allowing you to do anything else.